# WebClient.DownloadString is 12 times faster than TcpClient?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, webclient, networkstream

It is now 8 hours and I am still trying to figure out. Code examples will be in VB.NET but I think they are also readable for C# users. Oh, and I accept C# solutions too.

This takes maximum 50ms:

```
Dim Data as String = wc.DownloadString("x.com")
```

While this takes 600ms average:

```
Dim client As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient
client.NoDelay = True
client.Client.NoDelay = True
client.Connect(IP, 80)
Dim ns As Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = client.GetStream
Dim gbytes(70000) As Byte
ns.Write(rbytes, 0, rbytes.Length)
ns.Flush()
ns.Read(gbytes, 0, gbytes.Length)
Dim Data as String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gbytes)
```

Yes, I have tried stream reader, diffrent buffer sizes including less and more than the length of the response(which is about 100,000 bytes). I am using exactly same headers which is used by WebClient and tried diffrent headers too. I have also tried every combination of NoDelay.

The thing is, I don't want to use `WebClient` and `NetworkStream.Flush` is commented to be useless in .NET so is there a way out?

Comment: The two methods are getting the same data via different mechanisms. I'd assume that `WebClient` is implemented with performance for HTTP traffic in mind, whereas `TcpClient` is lower-level and thus has no optimization for any specific scenario in place. Open up `System.Net.Http` in ILSpy and take a look at how `DownloadString` is implemented. I just did, and believe it or not the underlying implementation is fairly complex.

Comment: Another possibility, actually: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3e75347-5443-4cda-8e8d-96756678fb05/tcpclient-receive-delay-of-over-500ms?forum=netfxnetcom

Have you monitored the download with a tool like WireShark?

Comment: Well, the ns.Write part takes 0.02ms... So I think the problem starts in sending. In addition I have decreased, increased and even set the SendBufferSize to the same length as my outgoing data's length. No improvements.

Comment: Are you sure the entire payload downloaded in the TcpClient case? You don't check the return value of your .Read. I suspect it's much smaller than gbytes.Length. You should read again and again until .Read returns zero.

Comment: I have tried reading byte by byte. And I am so sure that it is more than 70,000 bytes. But I have tried reading 512, 1024, 2048 and many other numbers and nothing changed.